# How to read Instruments Leaks graph?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I understand the Leaks tool takes a snapshot every X (default 10) seconds. But do the red bars in the Leaks graph tell me the amount of leaked memory at that snapshot in time? Or do they signify the cumulative memory leaked?

In other words, towards the end of this graph, has my app leaked the cumulative of all red bars in memory, or has it leaked no memory because the bar has diminished in size, and then didn't appear at all in the last snapshot interval?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for yourself by clicking on the timeline and dragging over the time where the red bar is. A tooltip will open that tells you the number of leaks and the amount of leaked memory.

You'll find Instruments shows the cumulative total of leaks and leaked memory in the tooltip. In your screenshot, if you drag over the small red bar, the tooltip will report a higher number of leaks and leaked memory than it reports for the two taller bars in the graph.